# OS X Force displays to stay visible after display power is turned off

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

I have a TV connected to my Mac as an extended monitor.  When the TV is turned off, the Mac "loses" sight of it as if the cable was unplugged, and any output to it is either closed or pushed to my primary display.  Is there a way I can force OS X to freeze this monitor and not detect when it is connected/disconnected?  The effect would be that OS X thinks there's a monitor present regardless of if there actually is.

[The Gefen HDMI Detective](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/ext-hd-edidpn.jsp?prod_id=14859) does this, but if possible I'd like to save the money and implement a software solution.